# parse array with JSON from xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

Im trying to get php array to js using ajax and encoding by JSON in PHP and decoding in JS but unable to get the desired result.

I use var_dump just before i echo the encoded string and this is the output:

```php
$boardArrayEncoded = json_encode($boardArray);
var_dump($boardArrayEncoded);
echo $boardArrayEncoded;
```

this string after JSON_encode is:

```
string '{"1x1":0,"1x2":0,"1x3":0,"1x4":0,"1x5":0,"1x6":0,"2x1":0,"2x2":0,"2x3":0,"2x4":0,"2x5":0,"2x6":0,"3x1":0,"3x2":0,"3x3":0,"3x4":0,"3x5":0,"3x6":0,"4x1":0,"4x2":0,"4x3":0,"4x4":0,"4x5":0,"4x6":0,"5x1":0,"5x2":0,"5x3":0,"5x4":0,"5x5":0,"5x6":0,"6x1":0,"6x2":0,"6x3":0,"6x4":0,"6x5":0,"6x6":0}'
```

in javascript i try parse it:

```js
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
{
   document.getElementById("logDiv1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

this is the xmlhttp.responseText:    `{"1x1":0,"1x2":0,"1x3":0,"1x4":0,"1x5":0,"1x6":0,"2x1":0,"2x2":0,"2x3":0,"2x4":0,"2x5":0,"2x6":0,"3x1":0,"3x2":0,"3x3":0,"3x4":0,"3x5":0,"3x6":0,"4x1":0,"4x2":0,"4x3":0,"4x4":0,"4x5":0,"4x6":0,"5x1":0,"5x2":0,"5x3":0,"5x4":0,"5x5":0,"5x6":0,"6x1":0,"6x2":0,"6x3":0,"6x4":0,"6x5":0,"6x6":0}`

On firebug i get syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error]   

array1 = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

what im doing wrong? i need to use this array in JS, how can I encode it properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to http://jsonlint.org/, the JSON you posted is valid. Are you sure that's what you get?

Comment: yeah, this all the output from the printings from var_dump and innerHTML.

Comment: Well, if `string ` is part of the response (which it is if you really have `var_dump` in your code) then that's the problem.

Comment: i tried JSON.parse( the above response text) it did not gave me any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the var_dump. It's printing output, which probably leads to the fact that the responseText you stated isn't the full responseText.

I expect your responseText to be:

```
string '{"1x1":0,"1x2":0,"1x3":0,"1x4":0,"1x5":0,"1x6":0,"2x1":0,"2x2":0,"2x3":0,"2x4":0,"2x5":0,"2x6":0,"3x1":0,"3x2":0,"3x3":0,"3x4":0,"3x5":0,"3x6":0,"4x1":0,"4x2":0,"4x3":0,"4x4":0,"4x5":0,"4x6":0,"5x1":0,"5x2":0,"5x3":0,"5x4":0,"5x5":0,"5x6":0,"6x1":0,"6x2":0,"6x3":0,"6x4":0,"6x5":0,"6x6":0}'
{"1x1":0,"1x2":0,"1x3":0,"1x4":0,"1x5":0,"1x6":0,"2x1":0,"2x2":0,"2x3":0,"2x4":0,"2x5":0,"2x6":0,"3x1":0,"3x2":0,"3x3":0,"3x4":0,"3x5":0,"3x6":0,"4x1":0,"4x2":0,"4x3":0,"4x4":0,"4x5":0,"4x6":0,"5x1":0,"5x2":0,"5x3":0,"5x4":0,"5x5":0,"5x6":0,"6x1":0,"6x2":0,"6x3":0,"6x4":0,"6x5":0,"6x6":0}
```

Comment: it did the job, i removed the var_dump and its working, probably the problem was the var_dump was writing to responseText and then the response was as you mentioned in your answer, preventing it from being in JSON correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Check content-type :

```
  header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you only have `echo $boardArrayEncoded;` and **no** other output. Do also make sure that you have no leading spaces or line breaks since this can also break valid JSON data. Before you do the echo, include `header('Content-type: application/json');` to prepare your output as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ELc8L/

```
var responseText='{"1x1":0,"1x2":0,"1x3":0,"1x4":0,"1x5":0,"1x6":0,"2x1":0,"2x2":0,"2x3":0,"2x4":0,"2x5":0,"2x6":0,"3x1":0,"3x2":0,"3x3":0,"3x4":0,"3x5":0,"3x6":0,"4x1":0,"4x2":0,"4x3":0,"4x4":0,"4x5":0,"4x6":0,"5x1":0,"5x2":0,"5x3":0,"5x4":0,"5x5":0,"5x6":0,"6x1":0,"6x2":0,"6x3":0,"6x4":0,"6x5":0,"6x6":0}'; // Your JSON string.
parsedJSON=eval('('+responseText+')'); // Parsed JSON. Object.
alert(parsedJSON["1x1"]); // Access object element's like this, because you can't write parsedJSON.1x1;
for(element in parsedJSON){
    document.body.innerHTML+=element+" => "+parsedJSON[element]+"<br />";
} // Just a vardump to show everything's perfect
```